# netsh causes syntax error in Win8

Tags: networking, windows-8, netsh

I create a `.bat` file for change network using `netsh`:

```
netsh interface ip set address name=Wireless source=static addr=192.168.43.100 mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=192.168.43.1
```

In Windows-7 work fine, but in Windows-8+ not work and return this error:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect

How use `netsh` command for change IP address in Windows-8?

> **Note:** I run the BAT file as Admin

Comment: have you tried 'address' instead of 'addr'?

Comment: @ErlisD. Thanks, I tried, but shows the same error: `syntax of the command is incorrect`

Comment: Try this one: `netsh interface set address name=Wireless source=static address=192.168.43.100 mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=192.168.43.1`
If that doesn't work, in cmd enter the commands separately, like: `netsh`, then `interface` and after that: `set address name=Wireless source=static addr=192.168.43.100 mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=192.168.43.1`

Comment: @ErlisD. Not work, shows `command not foud: set address name="Wireless"`

Comment: My bad! Try adding an ip between the interface and the set: `netsh interface ip set address name=Wireless source=static address=192.168.43.100 mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=192.168.43.1`